# login to black screen in 18.04

Tags: nvidia, login, 18.04

I recently upgraded to 18.04. Currently, I get to the login screen just fine. If I attempt to login, I am confronted with a black screen and nothing more. I can drop to the terminal at the login screen, login through the terminal, enter startx and now I'm at my desktop. I am pretty sure that this is an nvidia issue as I'm continuously getting crash reports popping up for libnvidia-gl-390 install, but when i try to install this manually from the terminal, no issues.

Output of "find ~/ -mount ! -user michael"

```
sudo find ~/ -mount ! -user michael
[sudo] password for michael: 
/home/michael/.wget-hsts
/home/michael/Downloads
/home/michael/.dbus
/home/michael/.dbus/session-bus
/home/michael/.dbus/session-bus/cd82760ca7c64274a03b987139d8bbd9-1
/home/michael/Videos
/home/michael/Documents
/home/michael/Pictures
/home/michael/Public
/home/michael/Music
/home/michael/Desktop
/home/michael/.cache/dconf
```

Comment: Will you answer these questions?  **1)** Which desktop session are you having problems logging into?  **2)** How many desktop sessions do you have in your login option?  **3)** Do you have the same issue with all of them?

Comment: 1) whatever is listed as Ubuntu, which I am assuming I'm 18.04 is gnome, 2) 2, gnome and unity, 3) yes

Comment: You will have at least two options.  You may have more since it's an upgrade rather than a fresh install.  Will you check, then answer the three questions from the first comment?  It's probably unlikely that they will all fail.  If they do all fail, that's important information for troubleshooting.

Comment: Right, I checked each that I have. Only those two options show up and the same thing happens with both.

Comment: What is the output of: `find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)`

Comment: added output to question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78084/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-michael-jarret).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have run some GUI application that has taken ownership of files in your personal area.  The login manager isn't working because it doesn't have sufficient permission for the configuration files.

You can retake ownership of the files in your personal space by running this command:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
```

After running this command, you won't have any problems logging in.

Also insure the integrity of your login manager.  You can do this by installing lightdm with:

```
$ sudo apt install lightdm
```

At the command configuration prompt select Lightdm.

You can toggle between the Lightdm login manager and the Gnome login manager with this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```