# Black screen problem after log in to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fan

I use ubuntu 19.10 and after update Nvidia, The system had problems. When I log in to ubuntu, the black screen appears and laptop's fan worked non-stop. I removed Nvidia drivers but The fan problem still existed.

Finally, installed Nvidia-440. Now, sometimes after turn on my laptop and log in, a black screen appears with The fan problem. The last time I used 
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041064/1051916).

After installing *lightdm* I can log in with no problems. But I'm not sure what will happen next time! Why these problems arise? Should I always use *lightdm*? How can I install the best Nvidia driver?

I have an Asus n552vw laptop.